# Onde colocar o Data Annotation? View Model ou Model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, entity-framework

Usando Entity Framework Code First, com *view model* e *model*.

Para criar uma coluna com `varchar(2)`, preciso colocar o `MaxLength(2)` no *model* e no *view model*?

Comment: se você está usando Entity Framework Code First, então provavelmente você está criando suas classes de domínio(no caso suas Models) que o EF irá mapear para o banco de dados:

 uma boa e ótima forma que eu uso bastante é o padrão Specifications. se você quiser eu preparo uma boa resposta com um exemplo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Não

*ViewModels* não servem para criar entidades em banco. `[MaxLength]` serve justamente para especificar a largura da coluna em banco. Portanto, `[MaxLength]` deve ser usada apenas em *Model*.

Para *ViewModels*, use [`[StringLength]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute.aspx).

Comment: Se por alguma razão eu tiver que mudar em de 2 para 4, vou ter que alterar nos dois lugares?

Comment: Ou quando eu criar minha View Model ela irá assumir as "regras" da Model?

Comment: Sim, vai ter que alterar em ambos.

Answer (score 2):

Depende de como você quer garantir isto. Me parece que você está querendo garantir sob todas circunstâncias que esta propriedade e consequentemente a coluna do banco de dados tenha 2 caracteres no máximo. Então coloque no *model*. É ele que vale para toda a aplicação.

Se você usa *view model*, use nele se quiser que apenas nesta circunstância a validação seja usada. Obviamente se houver conflito entre as duas, se tudo estiver correto, a do *model* deve prevalecer.